# When caching files based on hash characters, why use the last characters rather than the first?

Tags: caching, string-hashing

I have seen it suggested that you get better "load-balancing" within a cache by using the last characters of a hashed filename - it's what nginx does for example (proxy cache module). Can anyone explain why the last characters are used?

EDIT:

For example:

```
md5('asdf')
'912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570'
md5('asdg')
'7e6a6a87bf3ffb29a6dd9f14afdc3b88'
```

"seem" random enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to have lots of files that start with the same prefix.  By reversing the name you can increase the randmoness.

Comment: This is especially true if the filename is a path.

Comment: But the file names are hashed. The question is why are the last characters of a *hash* any more random than the first?

Comment: @jerd, there are different types of hashing algorithms.  md5/sha256/etc are used to generate a unique and consistent key from an input value for comparison.  Cache hashing algorithms generate a single number from an input value used for placing cached items within a much much smaller number of buckets.  Cache hashing algorithms are much less unique and less random.